# Linear Gradient not working in Firefox 11 canonical for Ubuntu

Tags: html, css

This is my css

```
    * {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, white); 
    }
```

and my html is just essential tags (no divs ,no nothing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<title>Corruption in India</title>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But its just not appearing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 11 doesn't support the new gradient syntax. The notation to use for older versions is:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue, white);
```

You would use both (and the rest of the prefixes) to cover all bases of course.

Comment: I'm doing this for a html css webpage designing competition ,So wouldn't it be better to just update the browser and take the laptop with me...